# What web-service can I use to send MMS from my web app?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, mms

I am looking for a web service API that I can use to send MMS messages.  Most web services like Twilio and TextMarks only support SMS.  I am looking for a similar service that supports MMS.  Are there any out there?

Answer (score 0):

www.clickatell.com sends mms. But it costs money. =]

Answer (score 0):

Mogreet.com has a web service API that supports MMS on most US carriers.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found the Orange API, but it currently only works in France and seems expensive:  http://www.orangepartner.com/site/enuk/access_orange_apis/instant_apis/mms_api/p_mms_api.jsp